# How can I show/hide component with JSF?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

How can I show/hide component with JSF?
I am currently trying so do the same with the help of javascript but not successfull.
I cannot use any third party libraries.

Thanks| Abhi

Comment: Do you want to show/hide it during page generation, or in reaction to some action on already generated page? The first one can be achieved by "rendered" attribute of JSF tags, the latter by JavaScript.

Comment: The component should be invisible when the page is rendered and it should be shown when user clicks on a image. If you can tell me the JS approach that will be great!

Comment: If you can use JSF 2.0 the `<f:ajax>` tag will allow you to easily update a part of the page instead of triggering a complete page refresh.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, you need to get a handle to the control via its [clientId](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId()). This example uses a JSF2 Facelets view with a request-scope binding to get a handle to the other control:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:head><title>Show/Hide</title></h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:button value="toggle"
               onclick="toggle('#{requestScope.foo.clientId}'); return false;" />
      <h:inputText binding="#{requestScope.foo}" id="x" style="display: block" />
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function toggle(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if(element.style.display == 'block') {
          element.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          element.style.display = 'block'
        }
      }
    </script>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Exactly how you do this will depend on the version of JSF you're working on. See this blog post for older JSF versions: [JSF: working with component identifiers](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html).

Comment: Completely agree with @jake-long: you're mixing JS with JSF. Although it is possible you are creating a mess, which is not compliant with best practices in modular development.

Answer (score 66):

You can actually accomplish this *without* JavaScript, using only JSF's `rendered` attribute, by enclosing the elements to be shown/hidden in a component that can itself be re-rendered, such as a panelGroup, at least in JSF2.  For example, the following JSF code shows or hides one or both of two dropdown lists depending on the value of a third.  An AJAX event is used to update the display:

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{workflowProcEditBean.performedBy}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="O" itemLabel="Originator" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="R" itemLabel="Role" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="E" itemLabel="Employee" />
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="perfbyselection" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="perfbyselection">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="performedbyroleid" value="#{workflowProcEditBean.performedByRoleID}"
                     rendered="#{workflowProcEditBean.performedBy eq 'R'}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="- Choose One -" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{workflowProcEditBean.roles}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="performedbyempid" value="#{workflowProcEditBean.performedByEmpID}"
                     rendered="#{workflowProcEditBean.performedBy eq 'E'}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="- Choose One -" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{workflowProcEditBean.employees}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: It should be noted this uses ajax and will create extra server requests. Although this may be preferable sometimes I would opt for a javascript based solution

Comment: It should be noted, that if you also want to submit the form, only the input fields (or here the SelectOneMenus) with rendered = true gets submitted.

Comment: For this to work for me, I had to add `onchange="submit()"` to the outer `<h:selectOneMenu>` element as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18787995/2577705. The `valueChangeListener` is not necessary, unless the change itself needs to be tracked.

Answer (score 7):

Use the "rendered" attribute available on most if not all tags in the h-namespace.

```
<h:outputText value="Hi George" rendered="#{Person.name == 'George'}" />
```

Comment: This is so far the most simple and best way to do it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Easiest way so far.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `<h:panelGroup ...>` tag with attribute `rendered`. If you set `true` to rendered, the content of `<h:panelGroup ...>` won't be shown. Your XHTML file should have something like this:

```xml
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{userBean.showPassword}">
    <h:outputText id="password" value="#{userBean.password}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

UserBean.java:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable{
    private boolean showPassword = false;
    private String password = "";

    public boolean isShowPassword(){
        return showPassword;
    }
    public void setPassword(password){
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the right idea, but the rendered attribute should be used on the components INSIDE the panelGroup, rather than on the panelGroup itself, if you want to be able to show/hide the components dynamically, as with an AJAX event.  If you use rendered on the panelGroup and its condition is initially false, you'll get an error the first time you try to update it because it won't exist on the page.

Answer (score 3):

One obvious solution would be to use javascript (which is not JSF). To implement this by JSF you should use AJAX. In this example, I use a radio button group to show and hide two set of components. In the back bean, I define a boolean switch.

```
private boolean switchComponents;

public boolean isSwitchComponents() {
    return switchComponents;
}

public void setSwitchComponents(boolean switchComponents) {
    this.switchComponents = switchComponents;
}
```

When the switch is true, one set of components will be shown and when it is false the other set will be shown.

```
 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{backbean.switchValue}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="showComponentSetOne" itemValue='true'/>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="showComponentSetTwo" itemValue='false'/>
   <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="componentsRoot"/>
 </h:selectOneRadio>


<H:panelGroup id="componentsRoot">
     <h:panelGroup rendered="#{backbean.switchValue}">
       <!--switchValue to be shown on switch value == true-->
     </h:panelGroup>

   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!backbean.switchValue}">
      <!--switchValue to be shown on switch value == false-->
   </h:panelGroup>
</H:panelGroup>
```

Note: on the ajax event we render components root. because components which are not rendered in the first place can't be [re-rendered on the ajax event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790993/3593084).

Also, note that if the "componentsRoot" and radio buttons are under different component hierarchy. you should reference it from the root (form root).

Answer (score 1):

check this below code.
this is for dropdown menu. In this if we select others then the text box will show otherwise text box will hide.

```
function show_txt(arg,arg1)
{
if(document.getElementById(arg).value=='other')
{
document.getElementById(arg1).style.display="block";
document.getElementById(arg).style.display="none";
}
else
{
document.getElementById(arg).style.display="block";
document.getElementById(arg1).style.display="none";
}
}
The HTML code here :

<select id="arg" onChange="show_txt('arg','arg1');">
<option>yes</option>
<option>No</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="arg1" style="display:none;">
```

or you can check this link
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690188/replacing-a-dropdown-menu-with-a-text-menu-in-javascript/3690220#3690220)

Comment: This is HTML + JS which works in my case too, but I am having problems with JSF.

Comment: @abhi if you want to click on image and then show the component then give image an id and use onClick event on IMG tag

Comment: Thanks Ricky, but thats what I m doing which is not working for me. Nothing happens when I click on image!