# Displaying selected tree node info in a layout

Tags: jsf, xhtml

in my pge i have this :

```
<p:layout style="min-width:1400px;min-height:600px;" id="layout">

   <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="300">
     a tree ...
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center" size="800">  
     tabs ..
     </p:layoutUnit>

 </p:layout>
```

when a user selects a tree node i should display  the selected node information  in a tab  component  and this tab is located in the  layoutUnit  positionned in the center (id="center")
initially this layoutUnit should be empty 
Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Does it need to be an ajax update?  Where is your managed bean code?  What do you think you should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `rendered` attribute of your tab component.

This `rendered` attribute could be toggled from "false" to "true" (this value would be held in a bean) when some `actionlistener` is triggered in your tree component.
Look at this question for concrete steps (and check the second answer, not the first):
[How can I show/hide component with JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf)

NB: this is not primefaces specific so I removed the tag from your question to reflect this.