# Richfaces a4j:jsFunction renders textbox but rendered validation fails

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

My test application contains two `h:inputText` and one `a4j:outputPanel` which is a trigger for rerendering both text fields. Both text fields are empty at the beginning and the second one is also invisible. After clicking the panel a method is called which sets both input values and also the boolean value for displaying the second text field. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:fm30x="http://myfaces.inter-forum.de/fm30x/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css" library="css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">

        <h:panelGrid>

            <h:inputText id="text" value="#{testBean.testString}"/>

            <h:inputText id="text2" value="#{testBean.trackingId}" rendered="#{testBean.showString}"/>

                <a4j:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="quote" onmousedown="begin();">              
                    <h:outputText value="Thats a test" ></h:outputText>
                </a4j:outputPanel>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <a4j:jsFunction name="begin" actionListener="#{testBean.start}" render="text text2" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when clicking on the panel only the first text field gets rendered and the second one is still invisible, although I have updated the boolean value in the ajax method inside the bean. It is also strange, that when I always return true for the `showString` value in the getter, the second text field value gets updated (I can see it this time because the second text field will be always rendered then). So all in all I can say that the updating of the actual values are correct but the `render` attribute of the `h:inputText` is not correctly evaluated by ajax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got conditionally rendered components rerendering them directly does not work. You have to wrap them in something and call render on the wrapper.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="wrapper">
    <h:inputText id="text" value="#{testBean.testString}"/>
    <h:inputText id="text2" value="#{testBean.trackingId}" rendered="#{testBean.showString}"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<a4j:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="quote" onmousedown="begin();">              
    <h:outputText value="Thats a test" ></h:outputText>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<a4j:jsFunction name="begin" actionListener="#{testBean.start}" render="wrapper" />
```

Bear in mind that `rendered="false"` doesn't mean the component is invisible, it means it doesn't exist in the component tree.

Comment: Thank you very much for this good answer, this helped me a lot. I also found a solution here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/jsf-fajax-rendering`.