# Show/Hide components in primefaces 5/JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I thought this would be easy but I just cannot get it. I have a drop down and based on selection, I should be able to show/Hide another drop down based on a boolean. By default the boolean is false and only when it is true should the second drop down be rendered:

My page:

```
 <h:outputLabel value="Select Report: "/>
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{daily.reportname}" id="sector"  style="width: 250px;"> 
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{daily.reportType()}"/>
                                        <p:ajax  event="change" update="branchrender"  listener="#{daily.selectedReport()}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
 <h:panelGroup  id="branchrender" rendered="#{daily.showBranchDimension}">
                                        <h:outputText value="Branch" />
                                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{accounts.branchs}" id="branch"  style="width: 250px;"> 
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL" />
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{dimensions.branchCode()}"/>                    
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
```

My selected report Method:

```
public void selectedReport() {
        if (reportname.startsWith("cust_")) {
            custrepname = reportname;
            useBranch = pr.getCustRepProperties(custrepname + ".bi").getProperty("bi.useBranchDim");
            showBranchDimension = useBranch.equalsIgnoreCase("true");
            System.out.println("HERE: " + showBranchDimension);
        } else {
            custrepname = null;
        }

    }
```

`showBranchDimension` is a boolean having getter and setter:

```
public boolean isShowBranchDimension() {
        return showBranchDimension;
    }

    public void setShowBranchDimension(boolean showBranchDimension) {
        this.showBranchDimension = showBranchDimension;
    }
```

Am I missing something? The `System.out.println` prints true but the component is NOT rendered.

Comment: Check the scope of your bean in relation to the annotation that makes it a managed bean. And learn about rendering previously not rendered components: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the rendered component a `rendered` free because it must be exist when you submit the ajax request to server add another container to `branchrender` and move the rendered id to it

```
<h:panelGroup  id="branchrender">
     <h:panelGroup   rendered="#{daily.showBranchDimension}">
                                        <h:outputText value="Branch" />
                                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{accounts.branchs}" id="branch"  style="width: 250px;"> 
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL" />
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{dimensions.branchCode()}"/>                    
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
      </h:panelGroup> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790993/1460591) about this.

Comment: Thanks, Actually you are right.This worked.

Comment: Happy that could work :)

Comment: @YouYou: Many of these basic issues have duplicates in StackOverflow. Please search for them and mark them as such. It keeps SO clean.

Comment: @Kukeltje Ok I think you are right

Comment: @YouYou, Cool... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think problem could be with the way your implemented the p:ajax component. See the comments of [p:ajax listener method not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167354/pajax-listener-method-not-invoked).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. Still Not getting rendered despite the boolean being true.