# Updating multiple elements using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm trying to have multiple elements update when a selectOneMenu's item has been selected.

Right now it works for a single element that needs updating, I did this by following [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute), but since I'm working with `id` attributes, I can't re-use that.

After searching SO and various other sites (such as [this search](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsf%20update%20outputtext%20from%20bean), and a search I did on Google named *jsf ajax update outputtext*, I can't post the link since I don't have 10 rep), I'm just kind of stuck.

How do I proceed?

The AJAX call is being made from here:

```
<h:form class="navbar-form"> 
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{formHeader.selectedPersonId}" class="form-control">
        <f:selectItems value="#{persons.persons}" var="person" itemValue="#{person.id}" itemLabel="${person.fullName}"/>
        <f:ajax event="change"   listener="#{formHeader.impersonateListener}"  render=":selected-person" />        
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Which successfully updates this part:

```
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute -->
<h:panelGroup id="selected-person">
    <h:outputText>${auth.authPerson.fullName}</h:outputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

But now also needs to update the `<h:outputText>` here:

```
<h:outputText value="#{auth.authPerson.fullName}"/>
<span>Working @</span>
<span>Doing bla ....</span>
<span>messages</span>
```

I'm quite new to JSF just as a heads up. I'm probably doing something trivially wrong or missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `id` to your `outputText` taq and then add this `id` to the `render` attribute of your `f:ajax` tag.

You can update multiple elements whose ids are space-separated inside the `render` attribute.

Comment: Lots of duplicates in SO of basic questions like this. To keep SO clean, better search for them and mark the question as a duplicate... Thanks

Comment: @Kukeltje OK, will have it mind next time. thnx