# h:commandLink with f:ajax not rendering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.3

After migrating from Wildfly 8 to 16 and Java 8 to 11, I've been facing this problem that affect JSF `h:commandLink` and `f:ajax`.

I tried to render `:mainform`, `mainform`, `@form` ... But none is working. I have to manually reload the page to see the changes.

```
<h:form id="mainform">
    <div id="adiv">
    ...
      <h:commandLink value="Change statut" styleClass="grey" rendered="#{not bean.condition}">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.switchStatus}" execute="@this" render="@form" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Everything was right with WF8 and java 8.

How can I solve it ?

Edit: I tried with Richfaces and `a4j:commandLink` :

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Click here" reRender="@form"  actionListener="#{bean.switchStatus}"/>
```

and

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Click here" render="@form" execute="@form" actionListener="#{bean.switchStatus}"/>
```

Still no render.. Status is changed but page form is not refreshed.

Edit : 
After some research it seems to be an error with javascript rendering : 
Rendering works when I remove this function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                        var interval;
                        function countDown(){
                            var countdown=$("#countdown");
                            var count=20;
                            if(interval){
                                clearInterval(interval);
                            }
                            interval=setInterval(function(){
                                count--;
                                if(count > 0) {
                                    countdown.text(count);
                                } else {
                                    clearInterval(interval);
                                    interval=undefined;
                                    $("#cancelLnk").remove();
                                }
                            },1000);
                        }
                        function onCancel(data){
                            if(data&&data.status=="begin"&&interval){
                                clearInterval(interval);
                                interval=undefined;
                            }
                        }
                        //]]>
                    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've moved all js CDATA scripts outside form to be able to render it.

Comment: Then I would expect a 'nested cdata' error somewhere in your browser console

Comment: Right ! In the preview section I have a `<parseerror>` who stopped rendering at the end of CDATA `//]]>`.

Comment: So next time investigate things like this... And you would have known in advance and could have created a different question