# Primefaces autoUpdate only works once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a page with different calculations, which are done by ajax.
At the end of the page there should be a hint text, which is updated after each calculation.

For this I use the `autoUpdate` feature of Primefaces.

When I load the page initially the text is displayed correctly. Also after the first calculation the text is refreshed correctly.
But if I do further calculations, the text will not be changed anymore, no matter which value `balanceController.getBalance()` returns.
When I debug my code I see that `balanceController.getDetails()` runs correctly and also returns the desired text. Only the content on my page is not refreshed. When I manually reload the page (with the browser) the correct text appears.

What could be the cause that `<p:autoUpdate/>` is only executed during the first calculation and updates the tab content?

**balancePage.xhtml**

```
<p:tab title="Further details" rendered="#{balanceController.showDetails()}">
    <p:autoUpdate/>

    <h:outputText value="#{balanceController.details}"/>
</p:tab>
```

**BalanceController.java**

```
public String getDetails() {
    if ( getBalance() >= 0 ) {
        return "Your current balance is: " + Double.toString(getBalance());
    } else {
        return "Your credit has been used up!";
    }
}
```

Comment: is the `rendered` attribute `false` the second time? look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)

Comment: No, the rendered `attribute` is  `true`, it's only a propertie which is loaded when the application starts.

Comment: maybe try with updating via id. also check the browser's console (F12)

Comment: And always [mcve] and version info!

Comment: And if you try this in a jsf/primeFaces panel instead of a tab, does it then also only works once? Hint: you cannot update individual tabs only the content of a tab or the whole tabview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general a `p:tab` is not updateable, as the one who renders the `p:tab` is the parent component. Probably a `p:accordionPanel` or `p:tabView`.

So you can either move the `p:autoUpdate` to the parent component or move it inside the `h:outputText`.

NOTE: you probably need to add a id to the `h:outputText` as only components with rendered `id` are updatetable and `h:outputText` skips rendering the `id` when no `id` attribute is explicitly set.

Its also possible to solve it by wrapping it a `p:outputPanel`:

```xml
<p:tab title="Further details" rendered="#{balanceController.showDetails()}">
    <p:outputPanel>
       <p:autoUpdate/>
       #{balanceController.details}
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:tab>
```

I removed the `h:outputText` by performance reasons. IMO one should not use `h:outputText` for simple text (`escape` is not set to `false`) as this creates a `UICompoment` on the server side, which is not required.

Comment: _"In general a `p:tab` is not updateable"_ When is it? As far as I know it never is...