# How to render a datatable in JSF with AJAX clicking a commandButton

Tags: jsf, conditional-rendering, ajax-update

The objective is to have a `h:commandButton` and once I have clicked it,  using AJAX it will show the datatable "listaActores" (initially not showing it).

How could i do this? I have search for a solution, but I only found how to re-render the table once is present. My current code shows the table without doing nothing and clicking the button doesn't do anything.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit">
        <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="listaActores" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:dataTable id="listaActores" border="1"
        value="#{peliculasEditarBean.listaActores}" var="actor">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NOMBRE</f:facet>
            #{actor.nombre}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">APELLIDO</f:facet>
            #{actor.apellido}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat incomplete, but I'll answear anyway. Two things:

1. You're not saying how the table is "initially not showing". If there is some `rendered` on it, than you need to know that you must render a parent of the table. You can render only things that exist in rendered HTML. See for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790993/1411160).
2. If you'll put `action` in the button you'll see that the AJAX won't work. You need to change event to `action` or delete this attribute to use a default.

I preperend simple working example (BTW. Welcome on Stackoverflow :-) If you want get help faster [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be your's part of a question :-)):

(XHTML, added `action` to commandButton and remove `event` in `f:ajax`)

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit"
        action="#{peliculasEditarBean.initialize}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="listaActores" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:dataTable id="listaActores" border="1"
        value="#{peliculasEditarBean.listaActores}" var="actor">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NOMBRE</f:facet>
                #{actor.nombre}
            </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">APELLIDO</f:facet>
                #{actor.apellido}
            </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

(and bean)

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PeliculasEditarBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Actor> listaActores = null;

    public List<Actor> getListaActores() {
        return listaActores;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        listaActores = new ArrayList<>(3);
        listaActores.add(new Actor("foo", "bar"));
        listaActores.add(new Actor("foo", "foo"));
        listaActores.add(new Actor("bar", "bar"));
    }
    
    public class Actor {
        private final String nombre;
        private final String apellido;

        Actor(String nombre, String apellido) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
        }

        public String getApellido() {
            return apellido;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }
    }
}
```