# Trouble updating <p:outputpanel>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Ok, my problem is I can't update a component (cursos) from ajax, I do not really know why.

Here's my code:

Rol

```
                                    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.roles}" id="admin" disabled="#{checkView.validarAdm}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Administrador"></f:selectItem>                       
                                        <p:ajax listener="#{checkView.checkBoxAdmin()}" update="est"></p:ajax>
                                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>

                                    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.roles}" id="doce" disabled="#{checkView.validarDoc}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Docente"></f:selectItem>                          
                                        <p:ajax listener="#{checkView.checkBoxDoc()}" update="est, cursos"></p:ajax>
                                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>

                                    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.roles}" id="est" disabled="#{checkView.validarEst}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Estudiante"></f:selectItem>
                                        <p:ajax listener="#{checkView.checkBoxEst()}" update="doce, admin"></p:ajax>
                                    </h:selectManyCheckbox>

                                </div>
                                
                                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{checkView.check2 == true}" id="cursos" >
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <h:outputLabel class="form-label">Curso</h:outputLabel>
                                        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.cursos}">
                                            <c:forEach items="#{crearCursoView.listarCurso()}" var="lc">
                                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{lc}" itemLabel="#{lc.nombre}"></f:selectItem>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
                                    </div>
                                </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very common problem `rendered="#{checkView.check2 == true}"` because if your outputpanel is not rendered its not in the JSF tree so you can't update it.  The secret is to always use a wrapper component that has NO `rendered` flag on it so you can always just update that wrapper element to make the `p:outputPanel` show and hide.  use the example below and update `cursosWrapper` instead of `cursos`

```xml
<p:outputPanel id="cursosWrapper">
    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{checkView.check2 == true}" id="cursos" >
        <div class="mb-3">
            <h:outputLabel class="form-label">Curso</h:outputLabel>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.cursos}">
                <c:forEach items="#{crearCursoView.listarCurso()}" var="lc">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{lc}" itemLabel="#{lc.nombre}"></f:selectItem>
                </c:forEach>
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </div>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

...or use JSF passthrough to add `jsf:rendered` flag to the inner DIV.

```xml
<p:outputPanel id="cursosWrapper">
    <div class="mb-3" jsf:rendered="#{checkView.check2 == true}">
        <h:outputLabel class="form-label">Curso</h:outputLabel>
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usuarioSession.cursos}">
            <c:forEach items="#{crearCursoView.listarCurso()}" var="lc">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{lc}" itemLabel="#{lc.nombre}"></f:selectItem>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```