# p:messages rendering not working after ajax update

Tags: ajax, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have sheet(as datatable) . I am using ajax to update sheet(table) on change . I can update submit button render from backing bean . But i cant update my p:messages rendering like button. At the backing bean i am setting canMessageShow=false to not rendered p:messages but it still shows.

My code :

```
<form>

<p:commandButton id="submitButton" 
disabled="#{facesContext.validationFailed or !anybean.canSubmit}" 
 actionListener="#{anyBean.dosmethn}"  value="Submit"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" update="someSheet"/>

<pe:sheet id="someSheet"

<p:messages id="createTrashMessages" rendered="#{anyBean.canMessageShow}" autoUpdate="true"
            showDetail="true" showIcon="false" style="margin-left: 20px; width: 640px;"/>

<p:ajax event="change" global="false"
        update="submitButton someSheet createTrashMessages"
        listener="#{anyBean.editActionListener}" oncomplete="onCellEdit()"/>

<pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Item"
                readOnly="true"
                value="#{entity.item}"/>

<pe:sheet>

</form>
```

On my ajax update as you can see i am updating sheet and messages it self. Also i tried to remove from
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getAttributes()`  But p:messages still displays. Also i have checked
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getmessages` but it says no elements to display i mean its empty. How can i remove p:messages and not rendering upon ajax update. Because right now ajax updating button also setting canMessageShow to false. But p:messages still displaying.

My java version : 8
jsf 2.2.1
primefaces-extensions 6.2.10
primefaces 6.2

Comment: Why do you put  the remoteCommand and messages inside sheet? that does not make any sense

Comment: @tandraschko Sorry i updated code. I didnt put remotecommand inside sheet. But messages must be in sheet because ajax dont work if i put outside of sheet.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute

Comment: Agreed move all those components OUT of the sheet.