# Invoke action method on click of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, action, selectonemenu

I have the following drop down list:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee3}"  onclick="">
   <f:selectItems value="#{user.favCoffee3Value}" var="c"
   itemLabel="#{c.coffeeLabel}" itemValue="#{c.coffeeValue}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I would like to launch some method from the bean by drop down list item click. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `valueChangeListener` attribute, pointing to a method in the managed-bean and add a `submit()` in the `onchange` attribute.

The form should look like :

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{bean.valueChanged}" 
                     onchange="submit()">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="First" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Second" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

And the `valueChangeListener` method in the managed bean would be:

```
public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879138/when-to-use-valuechangelistener-or-fajax-listener/

Comment: I want to use this for working with items value, but when i change it, and use it codeб it shows me the previos value of the bean field associated with item

Comment: I solved this problem with <h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee1}" onchange="#{user.print()}" onclick="submit();">
      <f:selectItem itemValue="Cream Latte" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Cream Latte" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="Extreme Mocha" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha" />
      <f:selectItem itemValue="Buena Vista" itemLabel="Coffee3 - Buena Vista" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>

Answer (score 4):

As part of the basic JSF toolkit, you can use the `<f:ajax/>` tag to submit (using ajax) your input without need for a full page submit/refresh. Using your code sample

1. Define the `<f:ajax/>` tag as a child of the dropdown menu

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee3}"  onclick="">
      <f:selectItems value="#{user.favCoffee3Value}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.coffeeLabel}" itemValue="#{c.coffeeValue}" />
      <f:ajax listener="#{user.doSomething}"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```
2. Define a method (`doSomething()` in this example) in your backing bean that accepts an instance of `AjaxBehaviorEvent`

   ```
   public void doSomething(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe){
     //do what you want with your favCoffee3 variable here
   }
   ```

Further reading:

- [The `<f:ajax/>` tag documentation by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkabr.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for [a4j:support](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_support.html). Your `h:selectOneMenu` would look like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee3}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{user.favCoffee3Value}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.coffeeLabel}" itemValue="#{c.coffeeValue}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{user.onSelectOneMenuChange}">
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

You also need to add the following taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
```

Comment: You should at least mention that your answer requires that OP take on a new dependency of Richfaces