# Hide menu item from p:tieredMenu after the menu is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

I have the following

```
    <p:commandButton  id="menuButton"  value="ADD"  type="button" />
    <p:tieredMenu overlay="true" trigger="menuButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" style="width:150px">
        <p:menuitem id="addProspectLink">
            <p:commandLink action="#{myController.oneAction}" value="Menu One" immediate="true" process="@this">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{myController.idValue}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem id="searchProspectLink">
            <p:commandLink action="#{myController.twoAction}"  value="Menu Two" immediate="true" process="@this">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{myController.idValue}" />
            </p:commandLink>
    </p:menuitem>
</p:tieredMenu>
```

This works fine the way I wanted except that the menu is not hidden once it is clicked.

How can I amend this to hide the link once it is clicked?

Environment : JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 6.2 and Java 1.7

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf

Comment: Why do you add commandLinks as child of p:menuitem? Did you try to simply add those attributes (action/value/immediate...) to p:menuitem directly?

Comment: @Selaron because menu item does not support dialogReturn event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `p:tieredMenu` has some [client side api](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/tieredmenu?id=client-side-api), simply use the `hide()` method:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:commandButton id="menuButton" value="ADD" type="button" />
    <p:tieredMenu widgetVar="myMenu" overlay="true" trigger="menuButton"
        my="left top" at="left bottom">
        <p:menuitem id="a">
            <p:commandLink value="Reinstate Monica" process="@this"
                immediate="true" action="#{myBean.doSomething()}" onstart="PF('myMenu').hide();"/>
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:tieredMenu>
</h:form>
```

Not that I have added `p:tieredMenu widgetVar="myMenu"` and `p:commandLink onstart="PF('myMenu').hide();"`