# How can I hide JSF elements from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jsf

Hello I would like to hide some JSF elements from Javascript.

This is the xhtml page:

```
<b:container>
    <b:column >
         <b:form id="form1">  
             <b:selectOneMenu id="dropdownCnpCui" ajax="true" process="@this" label="..."  >         
                 <f:selectItems value="#{cereri.cnpcui}" var="beer" 
                                itemValue="#{beer}" itemLabel="#{beer}" />
            </b:selectOneMenu>
        </b:form>
    </b:column>
</b:container>
```

This is what I tried in Javascript file:

```
document.getElementById("form1:dropdownCnpCui").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

I also tried from css to hide it but doesn`t work. Can please someone give me an example ?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf

Comment: It doesnt answer the question and it doesn`t show an example...

Comment: You can use the `rendered` attribute at server side. With javascript, you have to look at the generated HTML code in your browser to do a `document.getElementById(myid).style.visibility=`

Comment: solved it using jQuery