# Replacing input fields from select choices (dropdown menu) with javascript

Tags: javascript, select, replace, drop-down-menu

Three things:  *select box 1, input box, select box 2*.
Based on the selections in *select box 1* (drop down list 1), I want either *input box* to be visible or *select box 2* to be visible, but not both.

Any help would be great :)  I am populating the options in select box 2 based on the choice in select box 1, but sometimes the user's choice entitles them to enter anything as the input, instead of just choosing from a list of values.

Does anyone know how I can hide/show or add/remove these elements from the page?  Would it be more-or-less the same if I had it create a new *input box* or *select box 2* every time the selection changes, and just destroy the last one?

Based on some other questions I notice that I can change the style:none like here
[StackOverflow> Replacing a dropdown menu with a text menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690188/replacing-a-dropdown-menu-with-a-text-menu-in-javascript)
is this the most desirable way to go about this?

I'm still learning the basics of js / DOM so any help (and explanation) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name='field' id='field' size='1' onchange='checkthis(this);'>
 <option>please select something</option>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 <option value='3'>3</option>
 <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='text1' name='text1' value='' />

<select name='field2' id='field2' size='1'>
 <option>please select something</option>
 <option value='1'>1</option>
 <option value='2'>2</option>
 <option value='3'>3</option>
 <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>

<input type='button' id='button' value='Click Me' />

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function checkthis(fld) {
 switch (fld.selectedIndex) {
  case 0:
   document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "block";
   break;
  case 1:
   document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "block";
   break;
  case 2:
   document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "none";
   break;
  case 3:
   document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("field2").style.display = "none";
   break;

 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hope that helps. you need to catch the onchange event of your first select and use the selectedIndex property to figure out how you want the other elements to be displayed (or not).

Comment: Very instructional.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide an element:

```
style="display:none;"
```

This will show an element:

```
style="display:block;"
```

You can handle the onchange event with a javascript function that will determine which element to hide or show, then change the style for the appropriate element.

BTW, this sort of work is MUCH easier when using JQuery.  (But it does shield you from learning some parts of the DOM, if that was your real goal.)

You could also use CSS classes to achieve the same goals, which works better if you want to change many style properties at once.  (JQuery would use the addClass, removeClass, or toggleClass functions.)

TOTALLY DIFFERENT APPROACH:

Maybe what you really want is a hybrid textbox / dropdown, called an autosuggest textbox.  It would let you select a value, while also allowing free typing when needed.

Comment: Although I don't need one for this application, autosuggest textboxes are really interesting!  Thanks for the one-up mushroom!